# Assembly- Using push and ESP-Register to store addresses

Tags: assembly, esp, register

I have found the following assembly lines presented in a tutorial which I do not understand:

```
 xor eax, eax      => clear, I know that, it makes eax = 0
 push eax          => push 0 on the stack
 push 0x68732f2f   => push "//sh" to the stack (the numbers are opcodes I guess, output of hexdump)
 push 0x6e69622f   => push "/bin" to the stack (again opcodes, representing "/bin" )
 mov ebx, esp      => put address of "/bin//sh\0" into ebx, via esp
 ....
```

**My question:** 
Why we put address of "/bin//sh" into ebx, via esp using the line mov ebx, esp for that ?

I draw a sketch:

```
         |                        |
         |------------------------|<-----ESP (I know that ESP always points to the top)
(a)      |  0x6e69622f  ("//sh")  |
         |------------------------|
(b)      |   0x68732f2f ("/bin")  |
         |------------------------|
(c)      |       0                |
         |------------------------|
```

**How I try to explain it to myself**(I am not sure if it is correct, but I thought to think about a little bit before I ask in that forum here):

ESP is a 32-bit register such that it is large enough to comprise the addresses at (a), (b) and (c) (which I marked above).

Is that right? I hope somebody can help me?

best regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let me clarify this:

`ESP` is a 32-bit register which contains a pointer to the stack.
It is not, by any means, big enough to `comprise the addresses at [...]`. It is just *pointing* at a memory location which holds `a`, `b`, and `c`.

---

What your exploit does is push a string to the stack. Look at the `/bin//sh` hexadecimal representation:

```
2f 62 69 6e 2f 2f 73 68
```

And now look at your assembly:

```
push 0x68732f2f
push 0x6e69622f
```

This is *not* any kind of opcodes, but rather the ASCII representation of the string, pushed as double words (basically, pushes the string in less instructions)

An alternative way would be:

```
push '/' ; same as push 0x2f
push 'b' ; same as push 0x62
push 'i' ; same as push 0x69
push 'n' ; same as push 0x6e
push '/' ; same as push 0x2f
push '/' ; same as push 0x2f
push 's' ; same as push 0x73
push 'h' ; same as push 0x68
```

Basically, it's doing the same as above, just in less instructions, by combining the ASCII codes together: `6e69622f` instead of `2f`, `62`, `69`, `6e` separated. It's also pushing a `0`, which is a [terminator for a C-style string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), so that the string ends there.

Now, the stack has `/bin//sh`, and all you gotta do is [call `sys_execve`](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/cs108/examples/shellcode32-1.c), by doing an `int 0x80` (interrupt), which is the way Linux uses to make syscalls.

Since [the syscall ID for `sys_execve` is 11](http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html), you move `11` to `al` (lower part of `eax`), and put the first argument into `ebx`, which is a *pointer to a string*. And since `ESP` is pointing to the top of the stack, and the top of the stack contains the `/bin//sh` we pushed before, the exploit assembly means this:

```
sys_execve("/bin//sh");
```

There you go, exploited! :)

Comment: thanks for the good explanation. It helps me a lot to understand it.

Comment: @user3097712 no problem, be sure to ask me if I didn't explain any part properly.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a technique to embed strings in the exploit, as u can define them in a regular fashion, as u need their address to access them but in an exploit these addresses are dynamic not static or constants.